# Get real SQLite run time?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

on SQLite one can use

```
sqlite> .timer ON
```

to get the execution time for a command. The version I currently have only has

```
CPU Time: user 0.000000 sys 0.000000
```

while newer version has a "real time" value. e.g.

```
Run Time: real 36.591 user 17.362911 sys 1.809612
```

Is there a way to calculate the real elapsed time of execution or how to make the "user time" and "sys time" make more useful?

Comment: The obvious answer is "update SQLite". Why can't you do this?

Comment: @CL. unfortunately I don't have a say in that, thx though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Unix `time` command to time anything.

```
$ time some-command
...
...
normal output
...
...
real    0m0.114s
user    0m0.039s
sys     0m0.065s
```

So, if you can put your SQL commands in a file that you can pass to sqlite, you can time the entire execution.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I thought of something like that but thought there might be overhead in the timing and was wondering if there's something that comes native with sqlite, if not i'll have to do something like this